# Symfony2 forms: Multiple upload widgets in one form: There's a big underlying I just can't swat

Tags: php, forms, symfony, upload, doctrine

Before I start posting some code I will expose the issue. Thing is the amount of code is extensive so in a first time I would like to hear about leads that I could investigate.

Here is my issue I am writing a form editors to make article type pages.
It is built on a three level collection...
A collection of components ( more or less columns) made of sections that I have links. 
The  article entity has two  "banner" properties that allows user to add multi-column pictures to the website. ( at top and bottom) They are 'Picture' entities that have an $image property

The sections are essentially a title with text but can otherwise be used to display an image. They have links that have images too.
Picture, Section and SectionLink have an $image property and the corresponding setter and getter. The property is an Image entity and a LinkImage entity for the links, all extending my File entity.

Being that they are collections components can be between 1 and 8, sections 0 to 4 for each components. Links something like 0 to 8.

Considering all the items that can have an image that's potentially a lot of images. All was going well ( Nah I am kidding it was a pain been stuck on it for about a month ) the uploads were taking place normally then I realized something was wrong as I tried adding some code  in the setImage methods for each level.

OK when I was uploading an image to replace another I did not want the old one to stay on the server so I added some code in setImage methods to remove old file on hard drive before replacing the local property $image.

I soon realized that instead of deleting the old file where I was replacing, uploading a picture would remove a file elsewhere in the article. Like for instance replacing an image with another in  component 0 section2 would delete it in  component 4 section 4. Usually it would delete  the first banner image.

I did some debugging and I realized using the file upload widgets did not call the proper methods. 
using a file upload in a section would call Picture::setImage
or it could call SectionLink::setImage. displaying a Image::getName in the setImage would show the name of a file corresponding the part that is confused with.

Before you ask, all those fields have separate ID and name html form attributes
For the section and sectionlink they are generated through prototyping and there is apparently no mistake

Similarly the upload widgets are generated in twig like such:

> {{ form_row(form.topBanner.image.file) }} {{
>   {{ form_widget(section.image.file) }} //in a multi level "for in" of course

I should add that if I don't use that "removal" code using an upload widget does set the image in the right place. It is when I try to access data from current image just before upload that gives this result. I must say that I am pretty green at debugging and that I am still using die/var_dump. I would be interested in what areas of my code I should put my nose in. Form, Entity, Controller, I have been looking everywhere and I have absolutely no clue what is going on.
Alternatively, if someone can come up with a better alternative for what I am trying to do, please do share. However I am very very  curious to know what is going on in the inner workings of Symfony ( Unless it's just me overlooking something obvious, as usual...

I hope someone can help me.. thank you!

Comment: I will share more as needed. But the size is huge, The javascript alone is more than 400 lines long. Just ask if you need something specific.

Answer (score 0):

Ok there was no bug it seems that all file widgets trigger a setter, whether they are used or not.
So using setImage for functionality was a bad idea.
I finally chose to do it in a controller, which makes sense after all.
To delete unused image files. I make an arraycollection of file image paths before handling the form. And after flushing the data, I make a new array with the new data I compare both arrays and I unlink the files that are not in the second one.